# Is this the correct way to insert text at the cursor in Android?

Tags: android, android-edittext

```
myInput.setText(myInput.getText().replace(myInput.getSelectionStart(), myInput.getSelectionEnd(), myText));
myInput.setSelection(myInput.getSelectionStart() + myText.length(), myInput.getSelectionEnd() + myText.length())
```

I ask because I think this code is much longer than it needs to be - Is there something shorter like `myInput.insertTextAtCursor(myText)` or is this the way everyone does it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is... but nothing prevents you from creating a utility method for this, if you find yourself repeatedly writing the same two lines.